# Does__getattr__ allow modifying passed value?

Tags: python, attributes, operator-overloading, getattr, getattribute

This is my code:

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 5

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        if attrname == 'value':
            return 10

X = myclass()
print X.value
```

I suppose the output value should be `10` (`__getattr__` modifies returned value). However output is `5`.

If I remove initialization of value:

```
class myclass:

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        if attrname == 'value':
            return 10

X = myclass()
print X.value
```

It works as expected (returns `10`).
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattr__` is only used for **missing** attributes. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self).

In your first example, `'value'` is not a missing attribute; it was set in `__init__`. Note that it doesn't matter where it was set, only that it exists.

If you must intercept **all** attribute access, you need to implement the [`__getattribute__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) instead.

Comment: But __setattr__ works for missing and not-missing attributes, right?

Comment: @HashDoe: yes, because setting an attribute would *add* that attribute if it was missing.

Comment: @HashDoe Also in 3.X for builtin accesses only `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` are not intercepted this matters for proxy classes when they proxy other objects and expect their operator overloading methods to be called.

Comment: @direprobs: you mean special methods perhaps? Yes, `__getattribute__` will be bypassed for some of those, but that's not specific to Python 3, that's the same in Python 2. See [*Special method lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, that's what I meant. Yup, you're right it's not just in 3.X but for new-style classes in both lines 2.X & 3.X.